# mysql query fails?

Tags: mysql, if-statement

Why does this mysql query fail?

```
UPDATE accounts 
SET motivation = IF(motivation+100 <= maxMotivation AND subscriberDays = 0, 
                    motivation+100)
```

I cannot get it to work, I am trying to do an update with an if statement

Answer (score 1):

You can rewrite it without `IF` at all:

```
UPDATE accounts 
SET motivation = motivation+100
WHERE motivation+100 <= maxMotivation AND subscriberDays = 0
```

and this query makes more sense

Answer (score 0):

[`IF` function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if) takes three arguments. Condition, value_if_true, value_if_false. You're missing the latter.

Comment: Ah so it is like a ternary operator!

Comment: @cgweb87 - Yes but it isn't an operator.